# In MVC, how can you [AllowHtml] on a property within an existing DLL's class?

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using [DataTables.NET](http://datatables.net/) in my MVC project. It has an `IDataTablesRequest` interface which usually is used as follows in an action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetTableData(IDataTablesRequest request) {
   ...
}
```

Part of the `IDataTablesRequest` interface contains an `AditionalParameters` property:

```
public IDictionary<string, object> AditionalParameters { get; set; }
```

I am trying to pass HTML attributes only within `AditionalParameters`, but MVC will not let me.

What I have tried is to implement my own `IDataTablesRequest` class such that I can prefix `AditionalParameters` with `[AllowHtml]`, but haven't had any success, because it contains a `Columns` property that fails to serialize on the MVC layer if it is implemented in that class:

```
public IEnumerable<IColumn> Columns { get; set; }
```

Because the stupid `IDataTablesRequest` interface contains sub-interfaces as part of it, I cannot re-implement `IColumn`. Any suggestions? From the JavaScript side of things, the data is already encoded when it is passed in since it has already been HTML encoded through `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value)` originally, but even after encoding it contains elements like `&` which MVC does not like when passing it back up into the `GetTableData` action, and I do not want to double-encode here because that can cause other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give more detail around what parts are html related. i.e the normal usage of [AllowHtml]

**AllowHtmlAttribute Class**

From mircosoft

> Allows a request to include HTML markup during model binding by
>   skipping request validation for the property. (It is strongly
>   recommended that your application explicitly check all models where
>   you disable request validation in order to prevent script exploits.)

I can not see what datatables have to do with [AllowHtml]

Comment: Regarding DataTables, they do not allow reimplementing `IDataTablesRequest` such that it works when you actually send up an AJAX request, as a result, you cannot have HTML inside of the `AditionalParameters` object, because MVC will block the request by default since it considers it to be a cyber attack.

Comment: and which part of the request is html

Comment: `AditionalParameters`, like the name implies is a dictionary you are free to use to set up key value pairs. Inside of additional parameters, I need to pass a string which contains HTML since its the only place to do so within this silly `IDataTablesRequest` object.

Comment: possible work around?....have you explore possibly send it separately, maybe that will not work for this... something like GetTableData(IDataTablesRequest request, string varHtml), I know you will need to more than that to allow varHtml but check if you consider this.

Comment: I did find a workaround just now, but not as complicated as that. The idea is to serialize objects on the server side using JSON.Encode and deserialize on the server side using JSON.Decode part of the System.Web.Helpers.Json class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: @Alexandru i don't follow how that would work? but if you do that all that counts ;-). you should post that solution if it works as I'm interested.

Comment: Could you add the java-script to the question plz

Comment: If you are interested, you should check out this other question I posted around the same time as this one which deals with the core problem of encoding and decoding HTML data to bypass MVCs security checks, which is a suitable solution in my case with what I am trying to do with my DataTables.NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654802/encoding-and-decoding-data-the-way-mvc-likes-it

Comment: Normally, I would just use [AllowHtml] on a property that uses HTML; in this case I can't find a way to do that so I just encode/decode the object I wish to use within `AditionalParameters` myself. Once encoded it will hopefully not contain any invalid characters.

Comment: Thanks, i understand what your saying but the part i cant figure out is: the html you are encoding... how are you displaying the encoded html? Then you are able to submit it back to the server... implying that you never decoded it on the client. implying that you never displayed it. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, it is not displayed, it goes into a `<select>` dropdown menu as an option's `value` attribute :P

Comment: sorry but could you tell me more.. like why are you storing the values for a dropdown as html?

Comment: I don't really have a choice, sometimes you have to work with an existing infrastructure that requires you to pass values like these back and forth and nobody really wants to change the infrastructure so you just have to man up and work with what you have

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by serializing and deserializing the `AditionalParameters` data I need to use on the server side by using `Json.Encode` and `Json.Decode` [which are a part of `System.Web.Helpers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json(v=vs.111).aspx).