# Encoding and decoding data the way MVC likes it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, encoding

I get data from MVC and encode it using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`. The problem is that MVC is not fond of form values containing the ampersand (&) symbol. For example, this...

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("'");
```

...results in `&#39;`. I fetch it on a `GET`, but if I submit this on a `POST`, I see the following action error:

```
Exception = {"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (selection=\"&#39;...\")."}
```

How can I encode my data on a `GET` in a way that makes MVC happy on a `POST`? I cannot set the property to `[AllowHtml]` because the model is within a separate class in a 3rd party DLL that I do not have control over, nor can I re-implement it, it seems.

Comment: Convert to Base64String instead of encoding it. If you like I can give you a javascript version of convert to and from Base64String

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I was thinking about that too, but we support some really old browsers with this product and I worry that they don't have support for base-64 conversion, or do they?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Ah, actually, nevermind! You are right, I can just base-64 encode and decode since my data only ever encodes/decodes from the server side.

Comment: so I'm adding it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better way of serializing/deserializing and I wanted to share it with everyone. Since I am using JavaScript and [DataTables.NET](http://datatables.net/) to do AJAX POST requests, I was able to use the `System.Web.Helpers` methods called [Json.Encode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode(v=vs.111).aspx) and [Json.Decode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.decode(v=vs.111).aspx), since they convert directly to JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) and back, it seems to work perfectly from JavaScript and up to MVC for my needs, and I should have used it all along.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dealing with Encoding and Decoding Urls just post the Base64String

Comment: I found a better way of serializing/deserializing and I wanted to share it with you; I will post it in an answer momentarily. Since I am using JavaScript and DataTables.NET to do AJAX POST requests, I was able to use the `System.Web.Helpers` method called `Json.Encode` and `Json.Decode`, since it converts directly to JSON, JavaScript Object Notation, it works perfectly from JavaScript and up to MVC, and I should have used it all along.

Answer (score 0):

How about using UrlEncode instead? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx